# Jenkins- multiple locations SVN. Is it possible to specify the build version

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I am new to Jenkins CI tool and I want to know if it is possible to specify what build to use when there are several projects, on different SVN locations, dependent on one another. For example, if I have the web project on SVN location1 and the backend project on SVN location2 and the web depends on the backend and one of the developers modifies something in backend, when the web developer does a commit, there will be a build failure. Is there the possibility to specify that the build from the web part should take into consideration build x from backend and not the newest build?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

yes that can be done. in Jenkins check for the **Build Triggers** options in your project web-settings and on the line **Build after other projects are built** you can specify the name of projects you want to build automatically after there has been changes made to the base project.

And similarly, in the **Post-build Actions**, look for **Build other projects**, where you can specify that if the base project builds successfully, it will automatically trigger a build on children projects.

Hope this helps.

Comment: And it works even if the projects are on different svn locations?

Comment: So, I can specify what children projects to build automatically. But if I have the parent project on location A and the child project on location B and the child project is modified, can I tell Jenkins somehow to build the parent project using an older version of the child? and not the current version. Because it can happen that the newest version of the parent is not compatible just yet with the newest version of the child.

Comment: "even if the projects are on different svn locations?" yes. For each project in Jenkins, you can specify where to access the source code. Then, wrt version nb, it gets a little bit more complicated but you can do so from Jenkins project config page. Where you specify the code location, you can also include at which version nb to check out with svn like (url@123). but then you may want to put this kind of logic in a script file.

Answer (score 0):

Your example of building a project against a specific version of another project is a little non-standard, but not impossible.

In your case, I would use Jenkins' ability to execute arbitrary scripts to help.  The script would take care of getting the correct version of the project that the one I want to build depends on.

Building on your example of a Web and Backend project, here's how I would do things without using a parametrized build:

1. Add a file to the repository of the Web project that stores the version of the Backend project to use
2. Configure a job to build the Web project when the source for the backend project changes in SVN.

   1. The project should check out the latest version of the Web project
   2. The first Build Step for the project would be a script (Execute Shell or Execute Windows Batch Command) that does the following:

      1. Gets the version of the Backend to use from the file containing the version info
      2. Either pulls the appropriate version of the Backend from the Backend's repository; or pulls the source of the appropriate version of the Backend's source
   3. (If you pulled the source only for the Backend, the next Build Step should be to build the Backend next)
   4. Build the Web piece
   5. Do any unit tests